# Readable, controllable iterators?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to craft [an LL(1) parser](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse16) for a deterministic context-free grammar. One of the things I'd like to be able to use, because it would enable *much* simpler, less greedy and more maintainable parsing of literal records like numbers, strings, comments and quotations is *k* tokens of lookahead, instead of just *1* token of lookahead.

Currently, my solution (which works but which I feel is suboptimal) is like (but not) the following:

```
for idx, tok in enumerate(toklist):
    if tok == "blah":
       do(stuff)
    elif tok == "notblah":
        try:
            toklist[idx + 1]
        except:
            whatever()
        else:
            something(else)
```

(You can see my actual, much larger implementation at the link above.)

Sometimes, like if the parser finds the beginning of a string or block comment, it would be nice to "jump" the iterator's current counter, such that many indices in the iterator would be skipped.

This *can* in theory be done with (for example) `idx += idx - toklist[idx+1:].index(COMMENT)`, however in practice, each time the loop repeats, the `idx` and `obj` are reinitialised with `toklist.next()`, overwriting any changes to the variables.

The obvious solution is a `while True:` or `while i < len(toklist): ... i += 1`, but there are a few glaring problems with those:

- Using `while` on an *iterator* like a list is really C-like and really *not* Pythonic, besides the fact it's horrendously unreadable and unclear compared to an `enumerate` on the iterator. (Also, for `while True:`, which may sometimes be desirable, you have to deal with `list index out of range`.)
- For each cycle of the `while`, there are two ways to get the current token:

  - using `toklist[i]` everywhere (ugly, when you could just iterate)
  - *assigning* `toklist[i]` to a shorter, more readable, less typo-vulnerable name each cycle. this has the disadvantage of hogging memory and being slow and inefficient.

Perhaps it can be argued that a `while` loop *is* what I should use, but I think `while` loops are for doing things until a condition is no longer true, and `for` loops are for iterating and looping finitely over an iterat*or*, and a(n iterative LL) parser should clearly implement the latter.

Is there a clean, Pythonic, efficient way to control and change arbitrarily the iterator's current index?

---

This is not a dupe of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33148641/) because all those answers use complicated, unreadable `while` loops, which is what I *don't* want.

Comment: Do you know of itertools?

Comment: @MadPhysicist A little bit (I know *of* it but not about what it provides), but I never bothered to check because I assumed what I want requires more than just a different iterator.

Comment: itertools lets you manipulate iterators. In your case, it could be used in conjunction with a custom iterator.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: `itertools` provides functions to work with iterators, but it's not general purpose iterator manipulation of the sort the OP wants. You can skip along an iterator with `islice` for instance, but it has to run out the iterator (discarding values, not skipping) and there is no way to back up an iterator in the general case (you can do terrible things with `tee` or `chain` to kinda, sorta, simulate it, but they're terrible and inflexible).

Comment: Agreed. That is exactly why the real solution is a custom iterator just like in your answer. I think the OP may receive some tangential benefit from looking at itertools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a clean, Pythonic, efficient way to control and change arbitrarily the iterator's current index?

No, there isn't. You could implement your own iterator type though; it wouldn't operate at the same speed (being implemented in Python), but it's doable. For example:

```
from collections.abc import Iterator

class SequenceIterator(Iterator):

    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.seq = seq
        self.idx = 0

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            ret = self.seq[self.idx]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.idx += 1
            return ret

    def seek(self, offset):
        self.idx += offset
```

To use it, you'd do something like:

```
# Created outside for loop so you have name to call seek on
myseqiter = SequenceIterator(myseq)

for x in myseqiter:
    if test(x):
        # do stuff with x
    else:
        # Seek somehow, e.g.
        myseqiter.seek(1)  # Skips the next value
```

Adding behaviors like providing the index as well as value is left as an exercise.

Comment: Huh, interesting. I'll play around with this, thank you.