# Can I "hook" variable reassignment?

Tags: python, variables

Python is a language in which the following is possible:

```
>>> class A(object):
...  def __eq__(self, _):
...   return True
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a == "slfjghsjdfhgklsfghksjd"
True
>>> a == -87346957234576293847658734659834628572384657346573465
True
>>> a == None
True
>>> a is None
False
```

Other things, like `gt` and `lt` are also "overloadable"<sup>1</sup> in this way, and this is a great feature, in my opinion.

I'm curious if the `=` assignment operator is also "overloadable"<sup>1</sup> in a similar kind of fashion, or if I'd have to recompile Python into [NotPython](http://jython.org) to do this.

(As far as I know, classes and objects don't implement some `__assign__` method; that's implemented with the C bytecode runner/compiler.)

Specifically, I want to implement an LL(*k*) parser by iterating on a token list, [without using an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734137/readable-controllable-iterators) such that I can change the iterator's index arbitrarily to jump to a given token.

The catch is that on a given cycle of the loop, if I've already arbitrarily modified the index in preparation for the next cycle (something I'll surely do a lot) the *last* thing I want to do is mess up that variable by adding one to it as if it hadn't been changed.

Probably the easiest, simplest solution to this is to have a flag that gets set on jumps and which is reset to `False` every cycle, but this can and will introduce tiny hiding bugs I'd like to avoid ahead of time. ([See here for what I mean -- this is the pathetic iterative LL(*1*) parser I'm rewriting, and I want its reincarnation to be *somewhat* maintainable and/or readable](https://github.com/catb0t/mouse16/blob/master/mouse16.py#L682).)

The flag solution:

```
idx = 0
while True:
  jmpd = False
  # maybe we jumped, maybe we didn't; how am I to know!?!?
  if jmpd == False:
    idx += 1
```

Great! One big drawback: at each possible branch resulting in an arbitrary change in the index, I have to set that flag. Trivial, perhaps (obviously in this example), but to me it seems like a harbinger of unreadable, bug-friendly code.

**What's the best way, without using a second variable, to test if a value's changed over time?**

<sup><sup>If your answer is, "there isn't one, just be quiet and use a flag variable", then I congratulate you for promoting bad code design. /s</sup></sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Yeah, I know it's not *technically* operator overloading; have you a better, more quickly understandable term?

Comment: No, you can't "overload" (I agree it's as good a word as any) `=` and still be Python. What about using the `weakref` library? Maybe with a callback? I don't pretend to understand the nuances of what you're trying to do but I'm interested.

Comment: @RickTeachey Well, like I showed in the first code block, it's not "overloading" in the C# sense because it's only "overloaded" for instances of that class. I know I can't change what `=` does in *general*, but I want to track its effects on a class, or I want to know how else I should do this.

Comment: @RickTeachey *"I don't pretend to understand the nuances of what you're trying to do"* Can you elaborate; should I explain a part of my question more fully?

Comment: I've always been wary of `weakref` simply because using it looks like a complete mess. I'll look into it, though

Comment: @cat I just think I need to read it a few more times. I think it's pretty well explained.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin now, that solves *my* problem; that doesn't mean there aren't better still ways

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin I was just about to suggest that - good thinking. Sometimes the answer is right in front of you.

Comment: Another way of doing it would be to create your own container - perhaps using the `collections.ABC` module - and overload the `__setitem__` method of your custom container to notify you have a change (similar to using `__setattr__` above).

Comment: @RickTeachey give that as an answer with an example -- it may be useful to me, or future readers!

Comment: One more way would be using the `__set__` method of a descriptor. So I guess it turns out there are at least 3 ways to overload `=` in python (`__setattr__`, `__setitem__`, `__set__`)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use another [magic method](https://rszalski.github.io/magicmethods/) to intercept assignment of the attribute. It's called `__setattr__()`. Here is an example of how to use it:

```
In [2]: class Test(object):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print(name, "changed to", value)
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
   ...:

In [3]: t = Test()

In [4]: t.name = 4
name changed to 4

In [5]: t.name = 5
name changed to 5
```