# reliable to read loop variable after loop in Python

Tags: python

Is it safe to read loop variable after loop (using Python 2)? My purpose is to check how many iterations in the loop are done.

Here is code to show the idea:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 2:
        break

print i # output is 1, is it safe to read i here?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is fine to read it there. This is because when you create a `for` loop, internally, it has a mechanism to **create** the `indexer` for you (in your case being `i`) and then increases it one by one by assigning new value to it every time. Thus, you can use the `i` after the `for` loop. Thus after:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 2:
        break
```

`i` isn't really dropped. To drop `i`, you can use `del` keyword:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 2:
        break    

del i #deleted here

print i # now this will give you error!
```

While to replace is, you just simply need to redefine it:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]

for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i] == 2:
        break    

i = [] #now this is a list, not an integer anymore

print i # now this will give you different result: []
```

Similarly, for example, if you create a list in an if block:

```
if i == 0: #suppose you really enter this block
   a = [] #a is created here

a.append(b) #but a can be used here, assuming the previous if is really entered
```

This is just how Python works.

Some related posts:

- [How to transform string into dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618307/how-to-transform-string-into-dict/35618686#35618686)
- ['For' loop behaviour in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35768738/for-loop-behaviour-in-python?lq=1)

Comment: Thanks Ian, vote up. :) What is the life scope of i? Even after the loop?

Comment: @LinMa yes, it is unlike compiled programming language like C#, once created the variable is there till you replace it or drop it. This is not the same when the variable is created inside a `def` scope though, the variable will only last within the `def`

Comment: Another way the variable goes away is when it goes out of scope.

Comment: Thanks Ian, what do you mean "till you replace it or drop it"? An example is appreciated?

Comment: Thanks @mprat, what is the scope here?

Comment: @LinMa OK, answer updated to also address your questions in comments. :)

Comment: @DSM thanks for the correction, phrase removed.

Comment: Thanks Ian, mark your reply as an answer. :)

Comment: @LinMa great! thanks! :) simply check out the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35618307/how-to-transform-string-into-dict/35618686#35618686) I gave you for further understanding on how `for` loop works.

Comment: Important caveat: `i` is bound after the loop **as long as the loop goes through at least one iteration**. Otherwise, it will be unbound and accessing it will raise a `NameError`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it, and it would be fine to do so, since the value of `i` in this case only gets incremented before the execution of the internal loop. It would make this code a bit harder to read, but it would get the job done. The variable `i` is created in the same scope as the for loop. If the example code you gave is the entire file, then `i` would go out of scope when the file exists. If the code example you gave was inside a function, `i` would be created inside the function, then go out of scope when the function returns / exits.

An alternate way of doing this would be to use the `for... in` construction for loops in Python, together with the `zip` method, and keep a variable:

```
for element, i in zip(a, range(len(a)):
    if element == 2:
        index = i
```

Then at the end, you are setting a new variable called `index` and not relying on loop variables.

Comment: Thanks mprat, vote up. Wondering what is the life scope of i? Even after the loop?

Comment: `i` exists after the loop, yes. It is created in the same scope as the loop is created in. In your example, it goes out of scope when the program finishes (assuming this is the whole program). If this program were inside a function, `i` would go out of scope when the function exited / returned.

Comment: Thanks mprat, vote up, when i will be destroyed (I mean out of scope), from your reply, it seems i always exists? An example is appreciated. :)